# Add a banner message to Jupyter Hub/Lab instances?

Tags: jupyter, banner

I'd like to add a banner to every Jupyter instance that is spawned by my users via Jupyter Hub/Lab.

Something to the effect of `Do not copy and paste code from the internet into this notebook.`

How can I accomplish such a thing?
Thank you!